# CODE format: can I avoid colourisation _and_ italicisation?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown, code, underscore

There seems to have been a recent change, whereby all text highlighted using the backtick formatting has acquired a colour background.  This is fine in a code block but irritating when the format is applied to a keyword or two in regular text like this.

Much of what I post is related to Oracle, which is old-fashioned enough to use underscores rather than CamelCase.  Unfortunately this clashes with the formatting for italicisation.  So I need to use backticks if I want to refer to (say) `DBA_TABLESPACES`, otherwise it comes out like this: DBA_TABLESPACES (provided there is a subsequent matching underscore _ ).

The advice to use <PRE> instead doesn't help in this scenario, as the underscore formatting takes precedence.

**Edit**

Thanks to whoever edited my question and "fixed" the formatting, but I deliberately wrote it that way to show what happens when a post has two _ in it.

Comment: On the edit, check the history: the DBA_TABLESPACES will never turn up in italics because it's intra-word. However, preview screws it (bug, see my comment below). The one who edited, only changed your title.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to make use of the underscore (_) but don't want the whole post to go italicrazy on you when there is another in the mix, escape them with a backslash (\).

So in your case, it would be like this:

```
DBA\_TABLESPACES
```

Comment: I knew there had to be a simple answer.  Thanks.

Comment: According to this post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26165/how-can-i-type-an-underscore-symbol-as-part-of-a-word inner word italication should be off. In other words: the backslash is not needed. The italics only shows in preview, not after submit.